# Python Sockets: Can only send/receive a message once

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

Whenever I send a message from my client to the server (or vice versa), I have to wait until I've sent a message from the other side for it to register.

server.py

```
from socket import *

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 80

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    message = raw_input("Send message: ")
    s.send(message)
    print s.recv(1024)
```

client.py

```
from socket import *

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 80

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
c,addr = s.accept()

while True:
    message = raw_input("Send message: ")
    c.send(message)
    print c.recv(1024)
```

Example:

server sends message

nothing happens on client side

client sends message

both server and client receive their messages

this will happen over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's obvious that you have to wait for "the other side" because you have `raw_input` calls sitting in your code that are waiting for the user to type something...

That said, you're also recv'ing 1024 bytes but sending much less, probably. Thus the recv() will usually hang until it has enough data (but not always, in which case it returns less). Remember that with lowlevel socket communication you have to properly take care of message sizes/boundaries yourself!

You can agree on a termination byte such as "\n" that signifies the boundary between messages, or another strategy is to prepend every message by a few bytes that signify the size of the message following it. You then recv() exactly that amount.  Or just send a fixed amount of data for every message.

What remains is that you still have to deal with the fact that send() and recv() sometimes don't send or receive everything: they have a return value that is important.   Using `sendall`, and `recv` with the `MSG_WAITALL` flag can take care of most issues, but there's no guarantee.

Read this https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket for starters.